# what is this waxy, viney houseplant

Tags: identification, houseplants

2 to 3 cm long, waxy elliptical leaves that alternate along the vine. Vines grow from central point or can sprout from leaf junctions.

[image: Pot plant with small waxy elliptical leaves]

Comment: Elephant bush? https://gardenerspath.com/plants/succulents/grow-elephant-bush/  Also known as dwarf jade. Are the leaves similar to a jade plant?

Comment: The leaves are not as puffy as an elephant bush or jade plant. And elephant plant leaves are opposite each other while this plant has leaves that alternate. It does remind me of a jade plant though.